# Private field not being set when fragment is created

Tags: android, kotlin

In my fragment I have the following code:

```
class {
   private val resetHash: String by argument(ARGUMENT_RESET_HASH)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       // resetHash is never set
   }
}
```

argument is defined as:

```
inline fun <reified T> Fragment.argument(argumentName: String): ReadOnlyProperty<Fragment, T> {
    return object : ReadOnlyProperty<Fragment, T> {
        override fun getValue(thisRef: Fragment, property: KProperty<*>): T {
            return arguments?.get(argumentName) as T
        }
    }
}
```

The private member resetHash never gets set. Even if I put a breakpoint on the line with private val, it never gets hit.

What can be preventing it from being set? I even tried putting a click handler in the onViewCreated method to see if it is set when I click on some button but it is never set.

Why won't the breakpoint get hit?

Comment: How is the `argument` delegate defined?

Comment: I updated the post to show it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `resetHash` property is delegated. Kotlin delegates are lazy. It won't be executed while you don't call it:

```
import kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class TestDelegate : ReadOnlyProperty<Any, String> {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        println("delegate called")
        return "test"
    }
}

class Test {
    val prop by TestDelegate()
}

fun main() {
    val test = Test()
    println("no call")
    println("prop: ${test.prop}")
}

// will print
// no call
// delegate called
// prop: test
```

Answer (score 1):

The following would work:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private val resetHash: String by argument(ARGUMENT_RESET_HASH)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        resetHash
        // it is set now
    }
```